# Shared linux terminal - accounting for resolution differences

Tags: javascript, linux, terminal, gnu-screen

I'm implementing a web-based, shared Linux terminal (using term.js), and one issue I'm facing is the potential screen size differences of various connected users. For e.g. if I set `export COLUMNS=160`, then people with small screens have badly formatted output when they do a `ls` etc.

I know `screen` allows you to share terminals - how does screen account for change in resolutions of individual users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On terminals with more lines than `screen`'s current height, the "logical" bottom of the screen is marked with a line of dashes. On terminals with less characters than `screen`'s current width, lines are truncated or also badly formatted. Having users have different terminal sizes is always a mess. `screen` fortunately has the command

> `Ctrl-A` `F` (fit): Resize the window to the current region size.

This allows a user to override a previous user's insane setting.